# Roslyn - Use CSharpCompilation to compile assembly to be used in another program compiled by CSharpCompilation

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-assembly, roslyn

I'm trying to compile an assembly using `CSharpCompilation` that has a simple class in it, that I can then reference in another program that is also compiled through `CSharpCompilation`. I have this code:

```
namespace CompilationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<Assembly> referencedAssemblies = new HashSet<Assembly>()
            {
                typeof(object).Assembly,
                Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("Microsoft.CSharp")), 
                Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("netstandard")),
                Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Runtime")),
                Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Linq")),
                Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName("System.Linq.Expressions"))
            };
            
            string greetingClass = @"
namespace TestLibraryAssembly
{
    public static class Greeting
    {
        public static string GetGreeting(string name)
        {
            return ""Hello, "" + name + ""!"";
        }
    }
}
";
            
            CSharpCompilation compilation1 = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                "TestLibraryAssembly",
                new []
                {
                    CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(greetingClass)
                },
                referencedAssemblies.Select(assembly => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assembly.Location)).ToList(),
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
            );
            MemoryStream memoryStream1 = new MemoryStream();
            EmitResult emitResult1 = compilation1.Emit(memoryStream1);
            memoryStream1.Position = 0;
            MetadataReference testLibraryReference = MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(memoryStream1);

            string programCode = @"
using TestLibraryAssembly;

namespace TestProgram
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            string greeting = Greeting.GetGreeting(""Name"");
        }
    }
}
";
            
            CSharpCompilation compilation2 = CSharpCompilation.Create(
                "TestProgram",
                new []
                {
                    CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(programCode)
                },
                referencedAssemblies
                    .Select(assembly => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(assembly.Location))
                    .Concat(new List<MetadataReference> { testLibraryReference }).ToList(),
                new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
            );
            MemoryStream memoryStream2 = new MemoryStream();
            EmitResult emitResult2 = compilation2.Emit(memoryStream2);
            memoryStream2.Position = 0;
            
            Assembly programAssembly = Assembly.Load(memoryStream2.ToArray());
            Type programType = programAssembly.GetType("TestProgram.Program");
            MethodInfo method = programType.GetMethod("Main");
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(programType);
            method.Invoke(instance, null);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestLibraryAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'TestLibraryAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your example is how the Activator (`Activator.CreateInstance(programType);`) is trying to resolve the dependencies. It will look on the disk for files.

One way to work around this is to save the files on disk and later use `Activator.CreateInstanceFrom` to create an instance.

You can find here a snippet which is doing that:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;

namespace Playground
{
    public static class Program
    {
        private const string firstClass =
@"
namespace A
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Bar() => 21;
    }
}";

        private const string secondClass =
@"using A;

namespace B
{
    public class Test
    {
        public int GetValue() => new Foo().Bar();
    }
}
";

        public static void Main()
        {
            var firstAssemblyFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "A.dll");
            var secondAssemblyFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "B.dll");

            var compilation = CreateCompilation(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(firstClass), "A");
            var secondCompilation = CreateCompilation(CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(secondClass), "B")
                .AddReferences(compilation.ToMetadataReference());

            compilation.Emit(firstAssemblyFileName);
            secondCompilation.Emit(secondAssemblyFileName);

            dynamic testType = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(secondAssemblyFileName, "B.Test").Unwrap();
            var value = testType.GetValue();
        }

        private static CSharpCompilation CreateCompilation(SyntaxTree tree, string name) =>
            CSharpCompilation
                .Create(name, options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary))
                .AddReferences(MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(string).Assembly.Location))
                .AddSyntaxTrees(tree);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `netstandard`, there is no reference to `System.IO`.

Add this line to `referencedAssemblies` HashSet declaration section:

```
Assembly.Load("System.IO.FileSystem")
```

**Edited:**

Or more safe to use:

```
typeof(File).Assembly
```